# What is the correct syntax checking the .readyState of a website in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageloadstrategy

I'm trying to check the .readyState of a website using .execute_script but I keep getting an error.

I'm using a pageLoadStrategy of "none" in chromedriver so I'm trying to test that the websites readystate is no longer "loading".

Note: this question is Python-specific.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=20).until(
    driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'interactive'
)
```

> value = method(self._driver)
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I've also tried using lambda which doesn't throw an error, however printing the readystate will return conflicting results.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=20).until(
    lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'interactive'
)
print(driver.execute_script('return document.readyState'))
```

> loading

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377437/python-selenium-webdriver-writing-my-own-expected-condition

Answer (score 3):

Using `pageLoadStrategy` as **`none`** and then using *WebDriverWait* for `document.readyState` as **`interactive`** won't be a good approach. You can use either `pageLoadStrategy` or *WebDriverWait* for `document.readyState` as follows:

To configure `pageLoadStrategy` as **`None`** you can use either of the following solutions:

- ***Firefox*** :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
  #caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  interactive
  #caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  complete
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com")
  ```
- ***Chrome*** :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
  #caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  interactive
  #caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  complete
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com")
  ```

Using *WebDriverWait* to wait for `document.readyState` as **`eager`**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.readyState").equals("interactive"))
```

Using *WebDriverWait* to wait for `document.readyState` as **`normal`**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.readyState").equals("complete"))
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628)

---

### Outro

[Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-funtion-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleniu/50329056#50329056)

Comment: It seems OP has already configured 'pageLoadStrategy' as 'None' ... "I'm using a pageLoadStrategy of "none" in chromedriver"

Comment: @MosheSlavin Seems, I was not clear with OP's requirement, updated the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the condition into the JS:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=20).until(
    lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState === "interactive"')
)
print(driver.execute_script('return document.readyState'))
```

If the website is in angular you can use `pendingRequests.length === 0` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56629449/8179099).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution seems to work with "interactive" but when trying ` lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete'") ` I get the same "loading" in the print statement

Comment: Try: `lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState == "complete"')`