# Is it possible to resume Selenium code when the browser lands on a certain url?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, document-ready

Simple question, is it possible to resume selenium code the moment the browser lands on a certain URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

WebDriverWait(driver, sys.maxsize - 1).until(lambda s: s.current_url == "https://www.myurl.com/")
```

Comment: What does `sys.maxsize - 1` does?

Comment: It will wait forever

Comment: or more accurately, for 2^64 - 1 seconds

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `get()` method, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) executes the next line only when the browser attains *`document.readyState` equals **`complete`***.

So you don't have to take any additional steps for *Selenium* to resume code execution the moment the browser lands on a certain url.

However, in some rarest of the rare cases you may have to explicitly wait for `document.readyState` to be equal to **`complete`** using:

```
driver.execute_script("return document.readyState").equals("complete"))
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Is there a way with python-selenium to wait until all elements of a page has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832693/is-there-a-way-with-python-selenium-to-wait-until-all-elements-of-a-page-has-loa/47833358#47833358)
- [What is the correct syntax checking the .readyState of a website in Selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728656/what-is-the-correct-syntax-checking-the-readystate-of-a-website-in-selenium-pyt/56737282#56737282)