# Can Selenium detect when webpage finishes loading in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriverwait, document-ready, pageloadstrategy

In python I wrote:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
except se.TimeoutException:
    return False
# Start Parsing
```

Even though I have waited for `readyState` for some websites when I parse it I see that there is no checkbox. But, If I add `time.sleep(5)` Before parsing for the same website I get that there is a checkbox.

My question is, how can I have a general solution that works with the majority of websites? I can't just write `time.sleep(5)` as some websites might need much more and some might finish within 0.001 seconds (which will have bad impact on performance...)

I just want to stimulate a real browser and not to handle anything before the refresh button appears again (which means everything was loaded).

Comment: is my question clear?

Comment: don't check for readystate... that's hacky and you don't really know when that will execute.  A get() will, by default, wait for page to load already.  It sounds like what you have there is a "lazy load" style site, that initially puts up placeholders and then populates things via JS after load.  It's a messy thing to deal with and you need a solution that would work for that particular site.  WebDriverWaits with proper/targeted expected conditions should solve it, though some lazy loading sites are trickier than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally web applications when accessed through *`get()`*, returns the control to the WebDriver only when [`document.readyState` equals to **`complete`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833358/7429447). So unless the AUT(Application under Test) behaves otherwise, the following line of code is typically an overhead:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
```

However, as per your test requirements you can configure the [pageLoadStrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script) either as:

- *`none`*
- *`eager`*
- *`normal`*

> You can find a detailed discussion in [What is the correct syntax checking the .readyState of a website in Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56737282/7429447)

At this point, it is to be noted that using [`time.sleep(secs)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53589205/7429447) without any specific condition to achieve ***defeats the purpose of Automation*** and should be avoided at any cost.

---

### Solution

The generic approach that would work with all the websites is to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) as per the prevailing test scenario. As an example:

- To wait for the presence of an element you need to invoke the expected_conditions of *`presence_of_element_located()`*
- To wait for the visibility of an element you need to invoke the expected_conditions of *`visibility_of_element_located()`*
- To wait for the element to be visible, enabled and interactable such that you can click it you need to invoke the expected_conditions of *`element_to_be_clickable()`*